Limit of $g(x)= x + x^2\exp(\frac{i}{x^2})$ as $x$ approaches $0$
Consider $g(x)= x + x^2 \exp (\frac{i}{x^2}); x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{*} $
Now, $x + x^2 \exp (\frac{i}{x^2})=x + x^2 \exp (\frac{1}{-ix^2})$ and:
\begin{align*}
|\exp(\frac{1}{-ix^2})|=\exp(Re(\frac{1}{-ix^2}))
\end{align*}
And now,
\begin{align*}
&|g(x)|=|x+x^2 \exp (\frac{i}{x^2})|\\ \leq& \  |x|+x^2|\exp(\frac{1}{-ix^2})| \\ =& |x|+x^2\exp(Re(\frac{1}{-ix^2})) \underbrace{\to}_{x \to 0} \; 0
\end{align*}
So $\mathrm{lim}_{\ x \to 0}\ g(x)=0$
Are all the steps considered correct? Is the passage from '$i$ to $\frac{1}{-i}'$ needed?
EDIT: As pointed out by @Gary, $\frac{i}{x^2}$ is purely imaginary for non-zero real $x$ leading to $|\exp(\frac{i}{x^2})|=\exp(Re(\frac{i}{x^2}))=\exp(0)=1$

take $x=\epsilon e^{i\pi/4}$ so $x^2=\epsilon ^2 i$ and then what is the limit of $\epsilon^2 e^{1/\epsilon^2}$? If $x$ is real than indeed $|e^{i/x^2}|=1$ so the limit is zero but otherwise no

Is the limit $x \to 0$ or $x \to \infty$? Also, is $x \in \mathbb{R}$ or $x \in \mathbb{C}$?

The absolute value of that exponential is $1$ for all nonzero real $x$. Without that I can't see how you justify your last conclusion.
